# How to join two tables with multiple IDs from one table used in other table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to join two tables `tableA` and `tableB`, but the problem is that in `tableB` I have two *IDs* from `tableA` and I need to join them so I get both values. I would like to achieve it using Codeigniter's active record class. Here is a small demo:

```
tableA:
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ video_id ║ video_name ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ short      ║
║        2 ║ long       ║
║        3 ║ black      ║
║        4 ║ white      ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝

tableB
╔═════════╦════════╦════════╗
║ pair_id ║ pair_a ║ pair_b ║
╠═════════╬════════╬════════╣
║       1 ║      1 ║      2 ║
║       2 ║      1 ║      4 ║
║       3 ║      4 ║      3 ║
║       4 ║      3 ║      2 ║
╚═════════╩════════╩════════╝
```

this doesn't work:

```
$this->db->select('*')
         ->from("tableA")
         ->join('tableB AS A', 'tableA.video_id = A.pair_a')
         ->select("tableA.video_name as VIDEO_A")

         ->join('tableB AS B', 'tableA.video_id = B.pair_b')
         ->select("tableA.video_name as VIDEO_B")

         ->get()
         ->result();
```

The final result needs to be something like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VIDEO_A] => short
            [VIDEO_B] => long
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VIDEO_A] => short
            [VIDEO_B] => white
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VIDEO_A] => white
            [VIDEO_B] => black
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VIDEO_A] => black
            [VIDEO_B] => long
        )

)
```

Comment: what did you get by now?

Comment: VIDEO_A and VIDEO_B are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mix up tableA and tableB in your query. For each item in B you want something, so start joining there. Then, join renamed table, and select the items from the renamed tables.

```
->from("tableB")
->join('tableA AS pairA', 'pairA.video_id = tableB.pair_a')
->join('tableA AS pairB', 'pairB.video_id = tableB.pair_b')
->select("pairA.video_name as VIDEO_A, pairB.video_name as VIDEO_B")
```